# Is there a way to create manage path in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, managed-path

I am working on a new sharepoint online office 365 project. now when i access the admin site, i have the option to create new site collection under the following managed paths:-

1. sites.
2. team.

but i can not find any option to create new managed paths? either explicit or wildcard? so is this functionality not available in office 365??

Comment: Hi @john, you have asked the same question for 1 year ago :)

Comment: @M.Qassas ans is this still the case?